# Cannot fetch a value from a SELECT query inside a trigger

Tags: mysql, triggers

I am writing a trigger to UPDATE a row in a table AFTER INSERT on another table. Here are the scripts of the tables:

Table **inv_cost**

```
CREATE TABLE inv_cost (
  Username varchar(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  MachineType varchar(2) NOT NULL,
  Cost smallint(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (Username,MachineType),
)
```

Table **investigation**

```
CREATE TABLE investigation (
  Username varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  MachineType varchar(2) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
DELIMITER ;;
CREATE TRIGGER TRG1 AFTER INSERT ON investigation FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
    DECLARE cost INT DEFAULT 0;
    SET cost = (SELECT Cost FROM inv_cost WHERE Username = NEW.Username AND MachineType = NEW.MachineType);
    UPDATE test SET Balance = Balance - cost WHERE Username = New.Username;
END;;
DELIMITER ;
```

Table **investigator**

```
CREATE TABLE test (
  ID int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  Username varchar(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  Balance smallint(6) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (ID)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=4 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
DELIMITER ;;
CREATE TRIGGER TRG2 AFTER UPDATE ON test FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
    IF NEW.Balance > OLD.Balance THEN
        INSERT INTO payments SET Username = NEW.Username, PaymentOn = NOW(), Amount = NEW.Balance - OLD.Balance;
    END IF;
END;;
DELIMITER ;
```

The problem with trigger **TRG1** is that it does not compute the value of the variable **cost** from the SELECT statement, and always takes the value 0 or whatever is set to DEFAULT in its declaration. The UPDATE query on the next line works good (with whatever value **cost** takes from its declaration OR if it is assigned a const value like `SET cost = 100`;). The SELECT run separately gives the required value of **Cost**.

What is wrong with this code?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I tried `UPDATE surveyor SET Balance = Balance - NEW.VehicleType WHERE Username = New.Username;`, but the row is NOT being updated. That means, I am not able to get NEW.VehicleType from the INSERTed row. Am really I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use the sintax **SELECT field FROM table WHERE condition INTO variable**

```
DROP TRIGGER TRG1 IF EXISTS;
DELIMITER $$
 CREATE TRIGGER TRG1
 AFTER INSERT ON investigation
 FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
      DECLARE cst smallint;
      SELECT Cost FROM inv_cost WHERE Username = NEW.Username AND MachineType = NEW.MachineType INTO cst;
      UPDATE test SET Balance = Balance - cst WHERE Username = New.Username;
 END$$
 DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: Thanks for reply. But the result is the same.

Comment: what does this query return in mysql (replace NEW.Username and NEW.MachineType with the new values)? - SELECT Cost FROM inv_cost WHERE Username = NEW.Username AND MachineType = NEW.MachineType

Comment: It returns a numeric value that I have stored in the inv_cost table against Username and MachineType.

Comment: Should work. Are you sure the new trigger is up? Did you drop the previous trigger before adding the new one? (happened to me a few times)

Comment: May be not. But the changes in the trigger are reflected if I assign a constant value to the **cost** variable.

Comment: I dropped the trigger and recreated it with new name. But still no luck.

Comment: I have no luck on my local setup. Still trying to see where the problem is.