# Getting the last updated value from mysql table

Tags: php, mysql

Hey guys i have new to mysql development actually ....i have a table setup ..I just need to return the last updated value in mysql.

So i have researched more about it and i got a solution to create a trigger for the purpose..

So my code looks like

```
 CREATE TABLE CUSTOMERS(
   ID   INT              NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
   NAME VARCHAR (20)     NOT NULL,
   AGE  INT              NOT NULL,
   ADDRESS  CHAR (25) ,
   SALARY   DECIMAL (18, 2),
   PRIMARY KEY (ID)
);

INSERT INTO  CUSTOMERS (ID,NAME,AGE,ADDRESS,SALARY)  
VALUES (1,'aff',2,3,5),
 (2,'lolyeah',9,13,15);
```

The trigger looks like

```
CREATE TRIGGER getrandom 
AFTER UPDATE ON CUSTOMERS
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
UPDATE CUSTOMERS 
SET NAME = 'somerange'
WHERE ADDRESS = 3;
select NAME
END;
```

The above trigger didnt works actually..

what i need is that when i update the column CUSTOMERS i need to return the latest update value.

Hope you guys can help me..Thanx

Comment: There is more than 1 way you can do this. If you want a trigger to update like that, You would insert that last row into a new table...but that would be too much in my opinion. I would advise that you just add another column to your table with a datetime. When the record is updated, you update the time. You can then just select the table and sort by time updated.

Comment: @JoeSwindell i didnt get it actually..it would be really helpful if you post a sample code ..thanx

Comment: You could probably make use of [`LAST_INSERT_ID()`](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-last_insert_id.aspx) or PHP's [`mysqli_insert_id()`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.insert-id.php)

Comment: @Fred-ii- when i used lastinstertid in mysql  i get whole the value of the paticular column ..i just only need the last inserted value

Answer (score 3):

1. create a column with date_modified (date)
2. input a date when a new customer is added or updated
3. select * from customers order by Date_modified

code {

sql:

```
 CREATE TABLE CUSTOMERS(
   ID   INT              NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
   NAME VARCHAR (20)     NOT NULL,
   AGE  INT              NOT NULL,
   ADDRESS  CHAR (25) ,
   SALARY   DECIMAL (18, 2),
   Date_Modified date,
   PRIMARY KEY (ID)
);

INSERT INTO  CUSTOMERS (ID,NAME,AGE,ADDRESS,SALARY,Date_Modified)  
VALUES (1,'aff',2,3,5,'2012-11-10'),
 (2,'lolyeah',9,13,15,'2014-11-10');

SELECT * FROM CUSTOMERS ORDER BY Date_Modified ASC LIMIT 1;
```

sql no id:

```
 CREATE TABLE CUSTOMERS(
   ID   INT              NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
   NAME VARCHAR (20)     NOT NULL,
   AGE  INT              NOT NULL,
   ADDRESS  CHAR (25) ,
   SALARY   DECIMAL (18, 2),
   Date_Modified date,
   PRIMARY KEY (ID)
);

INSERT INTO  CUSTOMERS (,NAME,AGE,ADDRESS,SALARY,Date_Modified)  
VALUES ('aff',2,3,5,'2012-11-10'),
 ('lolyeah',9,13,15,'2014-11-10');

SELECT * FROM CUSTOMERS ORDER BY Date_Modified ASC LIMIT 1;
```

}

Comment: This answer is pretty much what I was saying in the comment. This will probably be your best solution.

Comment: @JoeSwindell yup tis was what i was looking for ..but actually how can i get a single value

Comment: @saptamasree SELECT * FROM CUSTOMERS ORDER BY Date_Modified ASC LIMIT 1;

Comment: SELECT * FROM CUSTOMERS ORDER BY Date_Modified ASC LIMIT 1;

Comment: @JoeSwindell it didnt helped actually ..could you post an sql fiddle sample

Comment: @saptamasree you shouldn't be creating an id also as its auto_increment and will generate it again for you. otherwise it would fail as sql would of used the id already.

Comment: how can 2 ppl paste the wrong answer here? o0 For the last modified row you need of course change ASC to DESC in both of the comments above: SELECT * FROM CUSTOMERS ORDER BY Date_Modified DESC LIMIT 1

Comment: @JoeSwindell see you didnt get my question actually..suppose there are some values in my row ...so when i update my row value i just need to outout he last updated value

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you want to archieve, but to make the trigger work:

```
CREATE TABLE CUSTOMERS(
ID   INT              NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
NAME VARCHAR (20)     NOT NULL,
AGE  INT              NOT NULL,
ADDRESS  CHAR (25) ,
SALARY   DECIMAL (18, 2),
PRIMARY KEY (ID)
);

CREATE TRIGGER `updcustomer` BEFORE UPDATE ON `CUSTOMERS`
FOR EACH ROW IF NEW.ADDRESS = 3 THEN
SET NEW.NAME = 'somerange';
END IF
```

Try it with

```
INSERT INTO  CUSTOMERS (ID,NAME,AGE,ADDRESS,SALARY)  
VALUES (1,'aff',2,3,5),
(2,'lolyeah',9,13,15);

UPDATE CUSTOMERS SET ADDRESS=3 WHERE ID=2
```

NAME of the second row will change to "somerange"

This trigger will fire after you UPDATE a row, not after you INSERT a row. For INSERT change the Trigger accordingly (UPDATE -> INSERT)

To get the last updated row add:

```
ALTER TABLE CUSTOMERS
ADD lastmodified TIMESTAMP 
DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP 
ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP;
```

and to get the last updated ID:

```
SELECT ID FROM CUSTOMERS ORDER BY lastmodified DESC LIMIT 1;
```

Also you should consider making the ID-field your primary key.

Comment: ..i didnt get it..where do i wanna add those alter table ...is it done after trigger or do i wanna do it seperately

Comment: the first code block is the correct syntax for the trigger from the question. if you dont need it and only want to get the last ID, alter your table with the ALTER-statement (paste in phpmyadmin -> SQL, exectue via php/python etc, or execute in mysql-client after selecting the right database), and then you can always get the last updated ID with the last SELECT-statement.

Comment: so here new.name means the value somerange is added to the new column right ??

Comment: It says: if you update a row then check if ADDRESS is 3, and if it is 3, then change NAME of the updated row to "somerange"

Comment: there is no "new" value, because its an UPDATE statement. it changes the old value of the updated row.

Comment: yup thank i got it ..support i want to display it using a select statement ..can i use the select statement inside trigger ??

Comment: trigger cant display anything, they have no output. but you can work with selects inside triggers of course. pls accept the answer, if it solves your question:-)

Comment: yeah surely ,i will ..could you please post an example  by using a select inside trigger by editing ur ans

Comment: If you need an example for a SELECT inside a trigger, look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9977690/cannot-fetch-a-value-from-a-select-query-inside-a-trigger

Comment: see you didnt get my question actually..suppose there are some values in my row ...so when i update my row value i just need to outout he last updated value ..

Comment: dont know what you mean by "output". there is no "output" in SQL triggers, as i wrote some lines above. triggers have no gui, they work behind the scenes. they cant "output" anything bc they have no frontend.

Comment: see suppose i have made some changes to my table with an update value ..what i need is to fetch the updated value only ...

Comment: @cari..when i run the code you gave me it didnt display the updated value ..it just displays the old value

Comment: I'm not sure what you do wrong. if i copy&paste all SQL commands from my post one after another up to `UPDATE CUSTOMERS SET ADDRESS=3 WHERE ID=2`, the NAME of the second row changes to `somerange`. There is no error in my code.